# How to solve this problem, my app keep crashing?

Tags: java, android, logcat

***it won't open. Here's what the log cat says about some of the problems and I don't know how to solve it because all the dependencies are there.***

**Unable to instantiate application androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication:**

***Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
because: Bad encoded_array value: Failure to verify dex file***

***Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file]]***

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file]]**

Answer (score 0):

Try this
In your manifest.xml change

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

to

```
android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Hope it helps